# Is it still possible to run SSIS Packages from DTEXECUI or similar?

Tags: sql-server, windows, ssis, visual-studio-2019, dtexec

My organization depends on SSIS packages to be run by data entry folks who are not trained, qualified, nor the least bit interested in database development. In our old SQL Server implementations (2008, 2012) they were able to install a standalone package execution utility that enabled them to run ETLs that we had developed in order to save them hours per day of manual manipulation of their data in order to make it compatible with our import tools.

When we switched CRM software, we updated to SQL Server 2019 and Visual Studio 2019. Our new CRM is far more finicky and difficult to satisfy than our old one, and does much less. (I was the only one who didn't want to switch, but even I didn't think the sales team was lying through their teeth like they obviously were in hindsight!) Now our ETLs developed in Visual Studio 2019 will not run from their standalone DTEXECUI, which is version 2 or 2.0. Examining the error codes confirms that this is a version compatibility issue.

After reading somewhat about it, I tried installing developer editions of SQL Server 2019 and SSIS on these data entry users' computers, with the understanding that the new versions of DTEXECUI only came with these suites. However, only the old version exists on their systems.

Does anyone know of any solution --ideally with such a package execution utility, but I am open to other suggestions-- that would allow such a non-developer user to run an SSIS package manually, such as DTEXECUI made possible in SQL Server 2008 and 2012?

Comment: What about triggering the SSIS package (or some other method of ETL) another way like an upload button on a website, dropping the file in a folder, or an email processor.

Comment: I almost forgot I could trigger these packages in an SSRS report, so that is going to be my new strategy, though last I checked we had some permissions issues about that, which I depend on others to remedy (because they have the permissions to edit permissions). Still worth a try. Thanks!